# Only one polish letter displayed correctly in xhtml2pdf generated pdf with ISO-8859-2 encoding

Tags: html, django, encoding, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to generate PDF with my data in it. I use xhtml2pdf:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-2")), result, encoding='ISO-8859-2')
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None

...

        elif response.POST.get("print"):
            context = {
                "ls": ls_query,
                "page_product": page_product,
            }
            pdf = render_to_pdf("print_zam.html", context)
            if pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                filename = "Zamówienie_%s.pdf" % ls_query
                content = "inline; filename=%s" % filename
                response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                return response
            return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

In my template i use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2">` but the only polish letter that is displayed correctly is Óó, the rest looks like a black square. Where seems to be the issue?

Comment: have you added **<!doctype html>** in your html

Comment: I haven't but it did not help.

Comment: I know how often people suggest using other libraries, and how annoying it is, but have you looked at pydf? https://github.com/tutorcruncher/pydf